# How do I allow switch to use uppercase or lower case?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, switch-statement

I'm working on learning JS and currently I'm trying to build a switch that allows capital or lowercase.
The fruits in my cases are what I'm trying to be allowed to entered. For example if "Pineapple" or "pineapple" is entered, it accepts both. Right now it's only accepting lower case and I'm not sure why.

Here's my code:

```
function favDrinks() {
var text;
var drinks = document.getElementById("inputbox").value;

//Switch(expression) to select code blocks to be executed.
switch (drinks) {
    //Cases to be tested against the expression.
    case "Pineapple", "pineapple":
        text = "Pineapple Rum Punch";
        break;
    case "Apple", "apple":
        text = "Apple Whiskey Sour";
        //If case matches, code will execute, and break will end switch block.
        break;
    case "Lime", "lime":
        text = "Tequila Lime Mojito Cocktail";
        break;
    case "Cherry", "cherry":
        text = "Cherry Lemonde Cocktail";
        break;
    case "Orange", "orange":
        text = "Orange Crush";
        break;
    case "Cranberry", "cranberry":
        toext = "Cranberry Cosmopolitan";
        break;
    case "Banana", "banana":
        text = "Dirty Banana Cocktail";
        break;
    case "Watermelon", "watermelon":
        text = "Watermelon Sangria";
        break;
    //If none of the cases match, default text is ran
    default: 
    text = "There are no drinks with that selection."
}
document.getElementById("favdrinkresult").innerHTML = text;
```

}

Comment: you could do this instead as :  `var drinks =  (document.getElementById("inputbox").value).toLowerCase();`

Comment: This is a lot better and saves me from adding more code, and just adding a simple line to the end of ''document.getElementById''' Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution to it and now it's working both ways.

I just added another case right under each case. For example:

```
switch (drinks) {
    //Cases to be tested against the expression.
    case "Pineapple":
    case "pineapple":
        text = "Pineapple Rum Punch";
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could call `toLowerCase` on the expression passed into the `switch` first:

```
switch (drinks.toLowerCase()) {
    //Cases to be tested against the expression.
    case "pineapple":
        text = "Pineapple Rum Punch";
        break;
```

You should strongly consider using an object instead, it'll be much more concise, less error prone, and easier to read and write:

```
const drinkNames = {
  pineapple: "Pineapple Rum Punch",
  apple: "Apple Whiskey Sour",
  // ...
};
const input = document.getElementById("inputbox");
const result = document.getElementById("favdrinkresult");
function favDrinks() {
  const inputValue = input.value;
  const text = drinkNames[inputValue.toLowerCase()];
  result.textContent = text || "There are no drinks with that selection.";
}
```

(also remember to use `.textContent` when setting *text* - only use `innerHTML` when setting or retrieving HTML markup in particular; `.textContent` is faster, safer, and more semantically appropriate otherwise)

Comment: Would you mind explaining to me why to use an object instead?

Comment: As the answer says, *it'll be much more concise, less error prone, and easier to read and write:*. If you want to write elegant, [DRY code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (which you should), `switch` is pretty much never the right choice.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I'm actually a student right now in Web Dev and this is what we're working on. Just trying to learn as much as I can and why things work the way they do. Thank you.